# JComboBox safety type difference in Java 7 and Java 6

Tags: generics, jcombobox, java-7, type-safety, java-6

I'm using project that can be compiled both Java 6 and Java 7 platforms.
One of the GUI classes is using JComboBox.
Since the JComboBox changed its specification in Java 7 to generic type, it requires parametric declaration of the component.

In Java 6 declaration like:

```
JComboBox mybox;
```

is okay and gives no errors, no warnings.

In Java 7 same component declaration gives warning

```
JComboBox is a raw type. References to generic type JComboBox<E> should be parameterized
```

Giving parameters as Java 7 requested:

```
JComboBox<String> mybox;
```

eliminates warnings for Java 7 platform, but I get the compilation error in Java 6.

What I can do in this case, so both Java platforms, 6 and 7, can live in peace for my project?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")` to ignore the generics warning. Note that `getSelectedItem` is not making use of the generics. Once you fully go for Java 7 remove/fix the warnings.

Comment: I don't like to leave in code SuppressWarnings.
Is it the only way?

Comment: Well Java 6 will not compile with generics on this class so you do not have much choice: keep the warnings or remove them, this is up to your personal preference, I would suppress them and create a ticket to remember dealing with them later.

Comment: In the body of your method, you may also need   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")